# META OG IMAGE from Database ID

Tags: php

I have a website, with a page to list multiple news, in the detailed page of a single news, i need to catch the id_news to put the meta og image and meta og tittle from the individual news.

I tried so many codes, but never get the result, always show a black page

I have this code in the top of the page:

```php
<?php
$caatid=intval($_GET['cid']);

$fetch_sql = "SELECT titulonews, completonews, postimage FROM noticiaspt where id_news='$catid'";
while($fetch_row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch_result))
    {
    $titulonews = $fetch_row['titulinews'];
    $postimage = $fetch_row['postimage'];
    $completonews = $fetch_row['completonews'];
    ?>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $titulonews; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://linktomysite.pt/admbo/postimages/<?php echo $postimage; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $completonews; ?>" /> <?php } ?>
```

But, in the body, the code to request the news with the right ID, works fine...

This is the other code i tried:

```php
<?php

    $catid=intval($_GET['cid']);

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"Select id_news,titulonews,completonews,postimage from noticiaspt where Is_Active=1 and id_news='$catid'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))  {
    ?>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo htmlentities($row['$titulonews']); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://linktomysite/admbo/postimages/<?php echo htmlentities($row['$postimage']); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo htmlentities($row['$completonews']); ?>" /> <?php } ?>
```

I can't find the problem. Any help?

Comment: If $titulonews, $postimage, $completonews contains strings, you need not to put quotation marks. Open view page source and check these meta tags, these might be printing
"http://linktomysite.pt/admbo/postimages/<?php echo $postimage; ?>"
instead of value of $postimage.
Better way use Concatenation of strings in php and directly call that variable in the content.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, be warned that your code is widely open for SQL injection - better have a look at prepared statements

Comment: Also, as you are still using `mysql_fetch_array`, I hope this is not a production system? That has been removed in PHP 7.0 years ago

Comment: Also, where did you define `$fetch_result`? Did you forget to copy it from your original code, or is it completely missing?

Comment: You do not execute the sql code anywhere. I also do not see a connection made to mysql. Others already mentioned that you should not be using mysql_*() functions.

Comment: @Akshay when i check meta tags, can't find the meta tags.

Comment: @NicoHaase Its a website to post some news, and a company info.  So, what type of code i need to learn to do this?

Comment: @NicoHaase Don't work when i put the link in facebook, its a blank page. i also have tried other code (updated on original post)

Comment: @Shadow the connection to database is in the page in other part of code, the page works fine, and show only the only  news i want... but for share the link in facebook, its all blank

Comment: @Bruno If you cannot find meta tags means you are not entering in while loop. Make sure $fetch_result has some value. If make sure you have given appropriate permissions if you are having issue after sharing.

Comment: @Akshay how? at this moment i'm lost, and can't find a good tutorial to learn how to put meta tags from individual id

Comment: "How to put meta tags" is not your problem currently, as they are pretty simple HTML constructs, and most probably you are writing the markup properly. "How to read data from the database" is the question you are probably asking, as you are not reading the data as you should. "I can't find the problem" is what you need to explain. What **exactly** is not working with the given code? Is the markup built as expected? Is there any error message? If you state "the page works fine", how could this be possible if something is not working fine?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have the main page News. with all news and a button "readmore" when you click readmore, you enter in a page with selected new (news.php?id=28) for example... And works fine. But get the result of meta tags from database, with the selected id, its that i can't put to work. No error message, when i put the link in the facebook, don't show anything :\

Comment: Before meta tag, write <script>console.log(<?php echo $postimage; ?>);</script>
and check the console. If you get nothing in the console that means you are not getting anything from database.

Comment: In this line, "while($fetch_row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch_result))" make sure it is $fetch_result is declared and assigned. I guess there should be $fetch_sql

Comment: @Akshay nops, nothing in the console :/

Comment: That means your not properly retrieving the data from database. Make sure every variable is spelled correctly. Also id_news, titulonews, completonews, postimage, Is_Active and id_news are spelled correctly in database with case sensitivity.

Comment: What is value of $fetch_result?

Comment: "i can't put to work" - what does that mean? How does the generated markup look like? How does that differ from the expected markup?

Comment: I dont know. i'm telling you, i can't find the problem. And dont understand what you mean with "What is value of $fetch_result?"

Comment: What have you **tried** to find the problem? Anything? Can you add the generated markup for that `<meta>` tag to your question by editing?

Comment: @NicoHaase tried the two diferent codes i have tried. also tried the select from i have in the same page for other situations....  query=mysqli_query "select......." while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) and after echo htmlentities($row['postimage'])

But For the this case, meta og:image, dont work. And i'm out of ideas, and dont understand some terms you're using. I dont speak/write english very good, just the base. And when you guys ask the value of fecth_result or i just dont understand what to do

Comment: Please share more details. "Dont work" is a description that does not contain what kind of problem you are facing. Is there any error thrown? Is the result different than expected?

Comment: @NicoHaase allready sayed, don't give any error on the page, can't see the meta tags on source page and when i try to post the link on facebook, don't have the info i want.

Answer (score 0):

There many points to talk about

1. you expect a single noticiaspt for the current page but you are using while() which in the end will get you the last rown returned by your database
2. this maybe is breaking your code `<?php } ?>`

Comment: `<?php } ?>` at the end of the example is just a closing bracket for the `while` loop.